# Ajax FormData() is returning null file when uploading a file and a string

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I have been looking for a way to upload a file to MongoDB by using the IP string to locate the correct document to upload. However, when I upload the file and check its field value in MongoDB it shows as null. I'm doubting that there might be an issue with the way I'm appending the file **OR** how I'm uploading it to MongoDB.

**HTML Code:**

```
<h5 class="modal-title h5Modal" id="htmlIP"></h5>
<div class="modal-body">
<form method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Uploadfile">Choose a File To Upload:</label>
<input type="file" id="Uploadfile" accept="image/*,.pdf,.pptx" class="file-path">
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-primary submitFile" data dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**Ajax Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submitFile').on('click',function(){

        formdata = new FormData();
        var ID = $('#htmlIP').text();
        var file = document.getElementById('Uploadfile').files[0];
        formdata.append('Uploadfile', file);
        formdata.append('IP', ID);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'PythonSubmit/',
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data.version);
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(err){
                alert(err);
             }
         });

    });
});
```

**Python Code:**

```
def PythonSubmit(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
       PC_IP = request.POST.get('IP', False)
       FileUploaded = request.POST.get('Uploadfile')

    res = PC.uploadFileToDB(PC_IP,FileUploaded)

    data = {
         'version' : res,
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**res** accesses the function **uploadFileToDB** inside **PC** class and add the values using $set method which is as follows:

**uploadFileToDB:**

```
@staticmethod
    def uploadFileToDB(PC_IP, file):
        PC_collection = PC._get_collection()
        try:
            PC_collection.find_one_and_update({"ip":PC_IP},
                                              {"$set":{"file":file}})
            res = "File Updated Successfully"
        except:
            print("couldn't write the file in DB")
            res = "Failed to upload the file"

        return res
```

Finding that the file field inside MongoDB has been updated to null means that my python code is locating the right document and inserting what it grabbed from Ajax function. So most likely the issue is with my Ajax.

Any suggestions or advice are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you had read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) you would see that the file is in `request.FILES` not in `request.POST`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped, but now I'm facing the issue where I have to use upload_to method to upload a file to a directory on my server rather than the database where I want it to be stored. I will update the question accordingly. Thanks again

Comment: make sure to add enctype="multipart/formdata" to your form tag

Comment: post a new question if it's going to be a different issue.

Comment: will read the documentation on it first and post a question if I face a problem.